# MSSQL Executing table filled with instructions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to change the collation for quite a lot tables including the columns. I already wrote a sql-statement which generate these for me. I wanted to create a stored procedure to automate this process. I created a table to store these generated statements and want to execute row after row. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems silly, but do you need to? This should be a one of process, so why write a stored procedure to do so.

Comment: ^ agree with @Larnu, how many times are you going to change all the collations across an entire instance? (Saving it as a stored procedure on instance 1 doesn't help you deploy the same changes to instance 2.)

Comment: Ignoring why, to execute something "row by row" you use a cursor. There are many examples (some good, many poor) of writing a cursor. I suggest you do a little research, read the documentation, and give it a try.

Comment: We got this problem with the wrong collation quite often therefore I got the task to automate this with a stored procedure. I guess the cursor option is the most promising one. Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  Use a cursor.